# why to use `list(map(str,input().split()))` when `input().split()` is already list

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, input

n here gets an input of a sentence like "hi, i am a beginner"

`n=list(map(str,input().split()))`

`input().split()`

i need to convert this into list of strings
both works but...

what is the difference?

Is list(map()) unneeded here ?

Answer (score 0):

`input()` always returns a string.

So `map(str,input().split())` is redundant and equivalent to `input().split()`

Reference: [input()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)

Answer (score 0):

The two ways are equivalent, you just need to write in the second way. But if you need a list of int type or other types, you can write like this:

```py
n = list(map(int, input().split()))
```